# Finding files matching path pattern and size criteria

Tags: find, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a server (RHEL 5) with 50+ websites currently running on the same eCommerce software, today I found one of the error log files was over 3GB in size.

Is there a way I can find all files over say 20MB on the system and empty them using the file pattern below?

```
/var/www/vhosts/*/httpdocs/system/logs/error.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /var/www/vhosts -name error.log -size 20M -exec ls -la {} \;
```

You can substitute any action you want for the "ls -la {}" - the {} is replaced with the filename.

Please note that this will find all files named error.log, not just those in httpdocs/system/logs/ folders.

Comment: I believe you mean `-size +20M`.